# How to create a placeholder that I will pass QImages to?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have two side-by-side areas where I will stream images to, passed as `QImage` objects.  I want them to force the `QImage`'s to be equal size, so it's just an area that gets passed the `QImage` and updates with the next `QImage` at the frame rate of a video, for example.

How can this be done?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: The only approach I've seen (and tried) is to use a QLabel and set its pixmap, but I feel like there should be a better way than a QLabel..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive your own widget from QWidget, override PaintEvent and use QPainter to paint your images

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter p(this);   

    p->setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform,true);

    //QRect destRegion0,destRegion1 are the shapes of the areas you want to draw into
    // image0/1 are the QImages, if you want to draw less than the full image 
    // supply a src rect instead of image.rect()
    p->drawImage(destRegion0,image0,image0.rect());
    p->drawImage(destRegion1,image1,image1.rect());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Perhaps it is because I am still new to QT, but I was wondering what '_win' is supposed to be, and why the parameter QPaintEvent * isn't given a name?  Thanks!

Comment: @zebra - sorry cut and paste, that was used to paint the background of the window black. The paint event doesn't have a variable because I'm not using it - just to avoid an unused var warning